# Please check my unit test via moq and c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Good day!

I just begin to start learn and practice doing tests(not TDD :)  ).
So, i wrote some little test, but dont know - is it right?It is green,but i cant do it red(fail).

I use [this msdn forum as example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0aea65a1-10d3-4b35-bac5-e1e2518e79c8/moq-error-the-following-setups-were-not-matched?forum=vsunittest) to do it.

So, i create an interface with one function. Parameter options- object with some field- options.Name for example.

```
public interface ICmdParseWrapper
{
    String getName(ServiceArgs options);
}

public class CmdParserWrapper
{
    private readonly ICmdParseWrapper dependency;
    public CmdParserWrapper(ICmdParseWrapper dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
     public String ValidateGetName(ServiceArgs options)
    {
        return this.dependency.getName(options);
    }

    public static String getName(ServiceArgs options)
    {
     return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Name)) ? options.Name : "Error in getName! is null or empty";
    }
}
```

So, i create testMethod and it passed! But i am not sure-am i right?I changet string "Error!..."  but test passed again.
    Here this class and test method.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod_getName()
    {
        ServiceArgs options=new ServiceArgs();
       // options.ModeName="";

        var mock = new Mock<ICmdParseWrapper>();
        mock.Setup(foo=>foo.getName(options)).Returns("Error in getName! is null or empty");
        var testClass = new CmdParserWrapper(mock.Object);
        String validateGetName = testClass.ValidateGetName(options);
        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

Please, can you tell me - is that test right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to start, but there are lot of things you can improve. I personally recommend you do TDD, because it helps you to write good Unit Tests.

Readability
Always give a good test method name. You don't need TestMethod in your test because they are tests.
Avoid ambiguise names such as GetName. If the test fails you don't know what condition the test causes to fail. Best thing is to provide more context in the test method name

If you want to check the GetName method being called

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateGetName_VerifyGetNameMethodIsCalled()
    {
        //Arrange    
        var mock = new Mock<ICmdParseWrapper>();
        var sut = new CmdParserWrapper(mock.Object);

        //Act
        sut.ValidateGetName(It.IsAny<ServiceArgs>());

        //Assert
        mock.Verify(x => x.GetName(It.IsAny<ServiceArgs>()));
    }
```

Also your ValidateGetName method doesn't have much behavior. It simply calls another service methid. The below setup is not needed.

```
     mock.Setup(foo=>foo.getName(options)).Returns("Error in getName! is null or empty");
```

Comment: As per the verification, if the dependency.GetName(options) method hasn't been called within your System Under Test, this test will fail.  Remember you are not testing the behaviour within dependency.GetName(options). Your dependency has been mocked. What you really testing is the behaviour of CmdParserWrapper.ValidateGetName(options) method.